# Damage of relocated jumps and dashes v2

Tags: league-of-legends

This is a follow op on my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121195/where-does-the-damage-of-relocated-dashes-land), in that one I got explained what happens to the damage of jumps when relocated by an **enemy**.

So what happens if you get relocated by an **ally** or more likely by your self.
Lets take [Tristana](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tristana) again (I love that cannon holding yordle).
Since she is able to do abilities during her jump I thought of three scenarios.

First scenario:

> > Tristana jumps, flashes in the air, lands

Second scenario:

> > Tristana jumps over a thresh lantern, clicks the lantern while in air (gets pulled), lands

Third scenario (and my favorite):

> > Tristana jumps, makes a kill or assists(jump resets), cast jump again(before landing), lands

For each scenario goes, Where does the damage land and where does Tris land?
And for the third where does both the damages land?

Comment: third scenario is impossible. first and second I imagine have the same effect

Comment: Why is the third scenario impossible?

Comment: [Global Cooldown](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=370269)

Comment: Isn't global cooldown very short, like 0.15s ? I don't think that would prevent chain jumping. In my opinion, there will be no damage in between two chained jumps, but you should try it by yourself to make sure.

Comment: @Aeronth GCD is 1 second like most games. It's just not as easily noticed.

Comment: @Nathan C: Unless you play Sona or Udyr, global cooldown is almost unnoticeable. Highly skilled players such as InSec (with Lee Sin) are known to occasionnally fire all of their spells within approximately half a second.

Comment: Im quit sure that not everything has a GCD, but maybe its a good idea to take this conversation to chat, cause i see this becoming a headed discussion :). and it would be nice if somebody explained that chat(never used it before).

Comment: I don't think this is different enough from your other question ([Where does the damage of relocated dashes land?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121195/where-does-the-damage-of-relocated-dashes-land)); instead, you should just edit that question to ask about being relocated by allies/yourself as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit lackluster unfortunately.

You can't flash or provide movement input (lantern) while in the air *with most abilities* - scenario 1 and 2 are usually impossible.

Tristana however is able to do this. If she Flashes, she will immediately move to the Flash's target location. Neither the original target nor the Flash target will have impact damage dealt.

I was unable to test Thresh's lantern, but if you can find a more patient Thresh you'll probably experience results similar to Flash.

Most resetting abilities are not immediate either, but Tristana's is. If you jump - kill - jump, she will immediately hit the ground *at her present location* and then jump to the new target.

Comment: "hit the ground at her present location and jump" Meaning she will also deal damage at her present location?

Comment: @SirDuckduck I wasn't able to confirm that, but the animation *does* play, unlike when she flashes out of the jump.